# I need that barcode to be used as soon as its scanned (no user "ok" button)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web, barcode-scanner

i have a asp web page and i need to scan product barcodes and do an event after each scan, i mean add that product to a grid. the only problem is how to call my event after barcode scanner scan barcode to a 'textbox' (no user "ok" button). my barcode scanner write new line after each scan not the real 'ENTER KEY code:13'

Comment: What barcode scanner do you use? How do you interact with it? Does it raise events? Where does it write this new line?

Comment: The barcode scanner is DATALOGIC Quick scan QD2330, USB Port, yes in other winform application, in NotePad i test

Answer (score 0):

Can you program the barcode scanner for a key combination after the data is set in the grid? The key combination after the scan would be the combination that saves the grid data. You would replace the code 13 it now does with a new combination. You would have to do this in the barcode firmware setup.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the textbox Textchanged event e.g;

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Label1.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(TextBox1.Text);
}
```

**[TextBox.Textchanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged.aspx)**